# How to return a List<string> based from a List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following signature method

```
 public static List<string> GetMembersForSharepointGroups(List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> adGroups)
```

And I need to make a linq query and return the values only

```
return adGroups.Where(p => p.Key.Equals("")
             || p.Key.Equals(""))
```

Obviosly it wont compile, how can I return a List from this linq query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
return adGroups.Where(p => p.Key.Equals("")) //no reason to check it twice
               .Select(item => item.Value)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Why is p being checked twice for and empty string?

Comment: @NickC You are right, didn't notice that. I copied it from OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly what `Select` does:

```
list.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the idea.

return adGroups.Select(p => p.Value).ToList();